# why all pull requests need to be merged at one time

Tags: git, workflow, git-workflow

I used to work in a mid-sized company that creates apps, and the common practice there for verification is to merge all the pull requests for bug fixes or comment in one of the fixes that does not work, wait till its done, and verify again before merging all the fixes/pull requests to the master branch. Is this a common practice? Is there another resource where I can get more information on this?

Comment: I think every company has its own "git" philosophy. Atlassian suggests [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) way.

Comment: no where near a common practice... there is a fallacy in this method that assumes  you won't need to do as many 'updates' on for each PR since they're all working off of one common commit. Realistically, you're just pushing conflicts into an unknown state as each PR is pulled ontop of each other without testing each interaction